# Endless boot loop when installing Intel Core i5-3350P in HP Pro 3300 SFF

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, intel-core-i5, chipset

I have acquired a HP Pro 3300 Small Form Factor/SFF (Product number: XT335EA#ABF), its motherboard has a LGA 1155 socket. It currently has an Intel Core i3-2120 processor installed, I want to upgrade to an Intel Core i5-3350P. The computer works great with its original processor.

I have two Intel Core i5-3350P, one of them seems to be dead, as one of its transistor is broken, the computer powers on when it's installed but nothing happens. I'm pretty sure this one is broken.

I have another Intel Core i5-3350P that seems to in great condition, this one has no broken transistors. When I install it and power on the computer, it seems to be caught in an endless boot loop, the computer powers on for a second, then shuts down and reboots, and this goes on until I turn off the power supply. When it's stuck in a boot loop, the power button doesn't do anything.

The Intel core i5-3350P should be compatible with the HP Pro 3300 SFF's motherboard, according to HP's documentation about this computer, it has an Intel H61 Express chipset:

https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-pro-3300-small-form-factor-pc/5099467/document/c02842372

And this chipset should be compatible with this CPU according to CPU-Upgrade:

http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-Intel_(chipsets)/H61_Express.html

The issue doesn't seem to come from the power supply, as I tried the computer's 220 Watts power supply and also a RaptorxX RT600-PSP 600 Watts power supply.

What causes this endless boot loop? How can I fix it?

Comment: You may have to re-install your operating system or re-image entirely. It's not optimal, but it can often solve boot looping issues.

Comment: @Shankensteinium The boot loop doesn't seems to come from the operating system (Windows 10), as the computer shuts down only a second after powering on.

Comment: Is  your machine actually managing to execute some boot steps, or do you just have power?

Comment: @Shankensteinium The computer powers on for only a few seconds, and then shuts down and reboot, there is no video output, even from a PCI-E grapics card.